# Banner not shown in FF-Chrome but correct shown in Edge. How to fix this for all?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, hyperlink

Here a banner link that will **not shown in FF-Chrome**, but **correct shown in Edge**. 
Is there something incorrect in the link?

How to fix this?

```
<a href="https://www.a2deals.nl/dagdeal/?tt=26414_1156502_250041_&amp;r=" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://ti.tradetracker.net/?c=26414&amp;m=1156502&amp;a=250041&amp;r=&amp;t=html" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="A2Deals | De beste deals bereikbaar zonder zorgen!" /></a>
```

Comment: Here it is working with Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Where is the problem?

Comment: _“How to fix this?”_ - probably by disabling your ad blocker …?

Comment: As I inform in thread it doesnt appear here in FireFox  and Chrome. I run all in latest versions.

Comment: Disable Adblocker is the solution. But how can I bypass / prevent the use of Adblocker on my page ?